# Can't center DIV because of other divs

Tags: html, css

yesterday I posted a question asking how can I center a div inside a div... Now I have another problem, I want to center a div on the screen. I want it to be in the middle and to take up 50% of the screen;
Here is a pic of the problem:
[image]

As you can see there isn't anything in the middle of the screen, that is my problem. Here is my HTML code:

```css
  * {
     font-size: 100%;
     font-family: Serif;
    }
    
    body {
     background: url("images/background.jpg") repeat;
     font-size: 100%;
    }
    
    .items {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 0;
     
    }
    #basicInfo{
     background-color: rgba(255,150,0,.8);
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #basicInfo:hover{
     background-color: rgba(255,150,0,1);
    }
    #basicInfo img{
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding-top: 16px;
    }
    #langs{
     background-color: rgba(255,150,0,.8);
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    #langs img{
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     padding-top: 16px;
    }
    #langs:hover{
     background-color: rgba(255,150,0,1);
    }
    .navbar {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     min-height: 5%;
    }
    .button{
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
     font-size: 2em;
     color: white;
     width: 33%;
     margin: 0 .16%;
     height: 100%;
     float: left;
    }
    .button:hover{
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    }
    .button a{
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #textSpace {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
     display: block;
     top: auto;
     bottom: auto;
    
    }
```

```html
<title>Mateo's About Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="items">
      <div id="basicInfo">
       <img src="images/question.png">
      </div>
      <div id="langs">
       <img src="images/code.jpg">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="textSpace">
      
     </div>
        <div class="navbar">
         <div class="button">
          <a href=""><b>Mateo</b></a>
         </div>
         <div class="button">
          <a href=""><b>Home</b></a>
         </div>
         <div class="button">
          <a href=""><b>Josh</b></a>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Any help is apriciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you clarify what is supposed to be in the center?

Comment: to center the text you can use `text-align: center`

Comment: Can you show what you are trying to center in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ffaycn6/)?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to center the #textSpace division. I want it to be in the middle of the screen. The problem is that it isn't even drawn to the screen nor positioned right. I know that it isn't positioned right because if I set my position to absolute I can see it but I don't think that will solve anything :)

Comment: @Akshay I have edited the Fiddle and set the position of the div to absolute, now it is shown but I still can't position it...

Answer (score 0):

To horizontally centre a div in the middle of the screen use:

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: Or if there is no vertical margin: `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work the problem is that it isn't even showing my division, you can see it on the pic.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the div with .item as the class that's causing the problem? With the width at 100% it's going to take up the whole screen. If you can confirm that's the div with the problem and give a bit more detail then I'll load up the code and have a a look at it.

Comment: @MKC Hi, I don't think this is the problem, I tried changing the height and it didn't work... Do you think you could run the code please? I can't seem to figure it out.... the only way I was able to show the #textSpace is by setting its position to absolute...

Comment: So you want #textSpace to take up 50% of the pages height?